# Will Using AntiForgeryToken sufficient to cover the authorization rule in a POST action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Will Using AntiForgeryToken covers the authorization rule in a POST action method
I have the following Create.cshtml view for creating a new Order:-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create New Order</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderType)
                @Html.TextBoxFor (m => m. OrderType)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderDate)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m. OrderDate)
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

The above view will be rendered when calling the following GET action method:-

```
[Authorize (Roles="customerservice")]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View("Create");
        }
```

and the POST action method is:-

```
     //
        // POST: /Create

        [HttpPost]

        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize (Roles="customerservice")]
        public ActionResult Create(Order r)
        {

            // Code goes here
            return View(model);
        }
```

Now my question is as follow:-

1. since i am using the Antiforgery token in my view , then i will guarantee that any valid call to the "POST:/ Create" is done; from the application itself + when  the user is inside the Create view, which means that the user is under the customerservice Role.
2. So does this means that if i remove the authorized attribute from the POST Create action method, then i am still secure? since if the application receive a "POST: Create" request then this means that the user is already authorized from the "Get: /Create" action method and that the request was sent from the Create view?
   Any comment about the above question.
   Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AntiForgeryToken` consist from three items:

- Attribute for action
- Helper method in view
- Cookie

`AntiForgeryToken` is not unique per each request, so if user is not logged, this is potentially risk.